# MPD can't connect to my sound card

Tags: sound, alsa, mpd

Here are my available cards (extra newline added between commands for readability):

```
audiohub@DYM-Portable-AudioHub:~$ sudo aplay -l
[sudo] password for audiohub: 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sunxicodec [sunxi-CODEC], device 0: M1 PCM [sunxi PCM]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: CODEC [USB Audio CODEC], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: X18XR18 [X18/XR18], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

audiohub@DYM-Portable-AudioHub:~$ arecord -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault:CARD=sunxicodec
    sunxi-CODEC, sunxi PCM
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=sunxicodec,DEV=0
    sunxi-CODEC, sunxi PCM
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=sunxicodec,DEV=0
    sunxi-CODEC, sunxi PCM
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=sunxicodec,DEV=0
    sunxi-CODEC, sunxi PCM
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=sunxicodec,DEV=0
    sunxi-CODEC, sunxi PCM
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=CODEC
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=X18XR18
    X18/XR18, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0
    X18/XR18, USB Audio
    Front speakers
surround40:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0
    X18/XR18, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0
    X18/XR18, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0
    X18/XR18, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0
    X18/XR18, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0
    X18/XR18, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0
    X18/XR18, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0
    X18/XR18, USB Audio
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0
    X18/XR18, USB Audio
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0
    X18/XR18, USB Audio
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0
    X18/XR18, USB Audio
    Hardware device with all software conversions

audiohub@DYM-Portable-AudioHub:~$
```

The on-board `sunxicodec` is not used, the USB `CODEC` is completely occupied for a different function, and I want `mpd` to play on the USB `X18XR18`.  No matter what I put in `/etc/mpd.conf`, `gmpc` always says:

[image]

I presently have this:

```
audio_output {
       type            "alsa"
       name            "XR18"
       device          "hw:2,0"
#       format          "48000:32:2"
}
```

It does the same thing with `"hw:1,0"` (`CODEC`), but it does play with `"hw:0,0"` (`sunxicodec`).  Unfortunately, that card requires some extra configuration to make it use analog instead of HDMI, so I haven't actually heard it to see if it sounds okay.

I know that the two USB cards work because `CODEC`'s function is flawless using its software, because `audacious` plays on `X18XR18`, and because I can simultaneously `arecord` `X18XR18`:

```
#!/bin/sh

REC_PATH=/home/audiohub/Recordings

arecord --device=hw:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0 --channels=18 --file-type=wav --format=S32_LE --rate=48000 --buffer-time=20000000 --max-file-time 300 "$REC_PATH/all_tracks.wav" &

# Force a filesystem sync every 1 second to keep the buffer small enough to write without missing samples
while true
do
    sleep 1
    sync
done
```

I also tried the `"hw:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0"` format in `/etc/mpd.conf`, instead of `"hw:2,0"`, but it did the same thing.

`aplay` does this:

```
audiohub@DYM-Portable-AudioHub:~$ aplay --device=hw:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0 --format=S32_LE --rate=48000 "/home/audiohub/Music/Waterlines/05 - Take Your Time.wav"
Playing WAVE '/home/audiohub/Music/Waterlines/05 - Take Your Time.wav' : Float 32 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
aplay: set_params:1233: Sample format non available
Available formats:
- S32_LE

audiohub@DYM-Portable-AudioHub:~$
```

The reason to not stick with `audacious`, even though it works, is that it relies on VNC for control (this player/recorder is headless) and the VNC server hangs up after a while and requires a reboot.  Since the jukebox is the only thing that really needs GUI control and `mpd` appears to do everything I need, I'd rather have that than `audacious`.

Any ideas to make it work, beyond what I've tried so far?

Comment: Does `aplay` with that device work? What users are allowed to access the device nodes in `/dev/snd/`? What user does `mpd` run as?

Comment: @CL.  That generated way too much information for a comment, so I added it to the question.

Comment: `--format` has no effect; the actual format of the .wav file is used. Try `plughw` instead of `hw`. Use `ls -l /dev/snd/`.

Comment: @CL. I think we're getting closer, but not quite there yet.  I updated the question again.  Please don't tell me that `/etc/mpd.conf` requires a numbered device because I've seen them swap.

Comment: I guess mpd plays to the wrong channels, or some mixer control is not set correctly.

Comment: @CL. I thought you were probably right, so I set up the `X18XR18` to show *all* activity on USB.  Still nothing.  Then...oh!  See my addition to the question.

Comment: @CL. Okay, after a bit more research, I'm still stuck, but I think the GUI playing silently is a different problem.  I'll start a new question for that and clean up this one so you can post an answer about `plughw` vs. `hw` to make it play at all.

Comment: @CL. Here's the other question: http://askubuntu.com/q/856392/321777  I hope I cleaned this one up satisfactorily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only format supported by the device is S32_LE. If mpd is not able to convert from the file's sample format to that, then you have to use an ALSA device that can do the conversion, if needed; i.e., replace `hw` with `plughw`.