# MPD appears to play, but there's no sound

Tags: sound, alsa, mpd

After solving [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/855951/321777), I have a second one.  It appears to play now, according to Gnome Music Player Client (`gmpc`), but there's no sound.  My `/etc/mpd.conf` so far has this in it:

```
audio_output {
       type            "alsa"
       name            "XR18"
       device          "plughw:CARD=X18XR18,DEV=0"
       format          "48000:32:2"
       auto_resample   "no"            # make MPD resample, instead of ALSA's libasound
       auto_channels   "no"            # play a multi-track audio file on its specified channels, no remapping
       always_on       "yes"           # keep the output device open, even when not playing
       mixer_type      "software"      # don't look for a hardware mixer because this card doesn't have one (at least not from the PC side)
#       mixer_device    "default"       # optional
#       mixer_control   "PCM"           # optional
#       mixer_index     "0"             # optional
}
```

With the default `mixer_type "hardware"`, `gmpc` appeared to be muted, and wouldn't allow me to unmute.  The mute command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, then type `mute`) did this:

[image]

Changing to `mixer_type "software"` got me a GUI volume control, but still no sound.  If I call it like this in my startup script, which itself gets called from `rc.local`:

```
mpd >> "$REC_PATH/Debug.log" 2>&1 &
```

then I get this in `Debug.log`:

```
socket: Failed to bind to '[::]:6600': Address already in use
```

I'm not sure what else would use that though.  `gmpc` connects anyway.  `aplay` with the first level of verbosity does this:

```
audiohub@DYM-Portable-AudioHub:~$ aplay -v -D plughw:X18XR18 "/home/audiohub/Music/Waterlines/05 - Take Your Time.wav"
Playing WAVE '/home/audiohub/Music/Waterlines/05 - Take Your Time.wav' : Float 32 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
Plug PCM: Linear Integer <-> Linear Float conversion PCM (S32_LE)
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : FLOAT_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 44100
  exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
  msbits       : 32
  buffer_size  : 13379
  period_size  : 3345
  period_time  : 75854
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 3345
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 13379
  stop_threshold   : 13379
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1753612288
Slave: Rate conversion PCM (48000, sformat=S32_LE)
Converter: linear-interpolation
Protocol version: 10002
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S32_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 44100
  exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
  msbits       : 32
  buffer_size  : 13379
  period_size  : 3345
  period_time  : 75854
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 3345
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 13379
  stop_threshold   : 13379
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1753612288
Slave: Route conversion PCM (sformat=S32_LE)
  Transformation table:
    0 <- 0
    1 <- 1
    2 <- none
    3 <- none
    4 <- none
    5 <- none
    6 <- none
    7 <- none
    8 <- none
    9 <- none
    10 <- none
    11 <- none
    12 <- none
    13 <- none
    14 <- none
    15 <- none
    16 <- none
    17 <- none
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S32_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 32
  buffer_size  : 14563
  period_size  : 3641
  period_time  : 75854
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 3641
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 10923
  stop_threshold   : 14563
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1908801536
Slave: Hardware PCM card 2 'X18/XR18' device 0 subdevice 0
Its setup is:
  stream       : PLAYBACK
  access       : MMAP_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S32_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 18
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 32
  buffer_size  : 14563
  period_size  : 3641
  period_time  : 75854
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 3641
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 10923
  stop_threshold   : 14563
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1908801536
  appl_ptr     : 0
  hw_ptr       : 0

audiohub@DYM-Portable-AudioHub:~$
```

And I see the meters dance in the `X18XR18`'s control app.  According to `alsamixer`, it has no controls at all, which is fine with me because it's actually this: https://www.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Mixers/Digital-Mixers/XR18/p/P0BI8  So the mute, volume, and a ton of other stuff is handled on that side through the app, which is available for free in the downloads section of that site.  I just want to throw audio at it.

Is there still something missing?

Comment: So `aplay` is able to generate sounds? What's the output of `aplay -v -D plughw:X18XR18 something.wav`?

Comment: @CL. It makes the meters dance today, and I heard it yesterday.  I have it home now, listening to other music, so I don't have speakers hooked up to it.  Updated the question.

Comment: The "Slave: Route conversion" shows that the two stereo channels end up at the first two of the eighteen channels of the device. Which channels do you actually want to use?

Comment: @CL. It doesn't really matter.  I can remap anything once it gets there.  But when I play something with `mpd` and look at all 18 meters, nothing lights up.  If all I wanted was playback, I could set it for 2/2 instead of 18/18 (another binary option in the control app).  But I really want the 18-track recording as well, using different software, the details of which are probably outside the scope of this question.

Comment: I don't know how mpd behaves for such a device (ask [them](https://www.musicpd.org/help/)), but that `auto_channels` setting looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions: You are using Ubuntu 16.04, and MPD V0.19.20.

I just found at https://www.musicpd.org/ there is a new version V0.19.21 that may fix your issue, also some issues I am having.

Good luck to both of us.

Mark.

Comment: It does indeed, now that I finally got back around to this project.  It needs to be compiled from source, though.  It's not in the repository so `apt-get install mpd` still gives the old one.