# Ncmpcpp says it is playing, but does not play anything

Tags: mpd, ncmpcpp

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I just installed mpd and ncmpcpp. Whenever I play any audio file, ncmpcpp detects the file and says it is playing, but no actual audio is playing. I followed [this tutorial on installing and configuring both mpc and ncmpcpp](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-to-install-and-setup-mpd-mpdscribble-ncmpcpp/8439). This is my mpd configuration:

```
music_directory     "~/Music"
playlist_directory      "~/Playlists"
db_file         "~/.local/share/mpd/mpd.db"
log_file            "~/.local/share/mpd/mpd.log"
pid_file            "~/.local/share/mpd/mpd.pid"
state_file          "~/.local/share/mpd/mpd.state"
sticker_file            "~/.local/share/mpd/sticker.sql"

bind_to_address     "127.0.0.1"
log_level           "default"
restore_paused "yes"
metadata_to_use "artist,album,title,track,name,genre,date"
auto_update "yes"

input {
        plugin "curl"
}

audio_output {
    type        "pulse"
    name        "pulse audio"
}

audio_output {
    type        "fifo"
    name        "mpd_fifo"
    path        "/tmp/mpd.fifo"
    format      "44100:16:2"
}
```

EDIT:
I would like to also clarify that I tried to install the latest version as it says in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/861514/977363), but I get this message for one of the packages:

```
E: Package 'libsystemd-daemon-dev' has no installation candidate
```

So, I download the .deb file and tried to install it from there. When I run "sudo dpkg -i" and the path to the file, I get this error:

```
dpkg: error processing package libsystemd-daemon-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libsystemd-daemon-dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own problem. I had to install the PulseAudio (What I'm using) GUI:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Run it, and fix the problem. I suppose for those using alsa it would the mixer, and so on for other sound server programs.